# Higher memory allocation to a function compared to class instance

Tags: python, memory

In a project I initially created a class for some file manipulations but then later identified that it had no reason being a class and rewrote it as a function.

The function is 30-40% faster (Python 3.8.5) but when I check the size of the objects in memory, the function is much larger than a class instance. I thought that all the internal plumbing that comes as a part of object superclass should make class instance larger than a function in most cases.

I'm thinking this might be an incorrect way to compare memory allocation but not sure how to do it properly.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path


class FileLocator:
    def __init__(self, folder: str):
        self.folder = Path(folder)
        self.files = [i for i in self.folder.glob('*')]

def file_locator(folder: str) -> list[Path]:
    return [i for i in Path(folder).glob('*')]

usr = os.getlogin()
ff = FileLocator(f'c:/Users/{usr}/Desktop')

size_class_instance = sys.getsizeof(ff)
size_function = sys.getsizeof(file_locator)

print(f' Class instance: {size_class_instance} bytes, function: {size_function} bytes')
```

And the output is:

```
Class instance: 48 bytes, function: 136 bytes
```

**EDIT:**
As per the discussion in the comments, I've added a new attribute to the `__init__` method:

```
class FileLocator:
    def __init__(self, folder: str):
        self.folder = Path(folder)
        self.files = [i for i in self.folder.glob('*')]
        self.val = list(range(10000))

usr = os.getlogin()
ff = FileLocator(f'c:/Users/{usr}/Desktop')
```

Now checking the size of the class in different ways:

```
sys.getsizeof(FileLocator) # Out 1064 - same as before
sys.getsizeof(FileLocator.__init__) : # Out: 136 - same as before
sys.getsizeof(ff)  # Out: 48 - previously was 36 bytes
```

Comment: A class instance doesn't contain the code. It contains a reference to the class, and the class dictionary contains references to each method.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks. So then for a correct comparison I should just compare the size of the class with the size of the function object? `sys.getsizeof(FileLocator)` vs `sys.getsizeof(file_locator)`?

Comment: No, the class doesn't contain the code, it contains references to the code.

Comment: You could compare `sys.getsizeof(file_locator)` with `sys.getsizeof(FileLocator.__init__)`

Comment: @Barmar, when I do `sys.getsizeof(FileLocator)` I get the size of 1064 bytes but `sys.getsizeof(FileLocator.__init__)` is 136 bytes, exactly the same as the function. So this suggests the class does include the code or the references are so heavy.

Comment: Try making the `__init__` function bigger. Does that change the size of the class?

Comment: @Barmar, I've added a new instance attribute `self.vals = list(range(10,000))` and you're right, the size of the class object remained at 1064 bytes, but `FileLocator.__init__` is still 136 bytes. So neither of the methods seem to reflect the change.

Comment: I meant to add more lines to the `__init__` function so you can see that the size of the function has nothing to do with the size of the class.

Comment: @Barmar, so yes, I've added the code in the `__init__` method. But neither of the two methods seem to reflect the change. On the other hand, if I now check the size of the instance, it is 48 bytes compared to 36 bytes previously.

Comment: That was my point -- adding code doesn't change the size of the class. That's the proof that the class size doesn't include the code.

Comment: Remember that instances are dictionaries. A dictionary is a hash table, and their size is not directly dependent on the number of keys because of overhead.

Comment: To understand this you need to learn all the details about how objects are implemented in Python, it's not completely intuitive.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, it is a bit confusing and now I'm not even sure if it makes sense to talk about the size of a class object.

Comment: Exactly. Especially since the size of the class is amortized among all the instances. It's not something you usually worry about.